# Any other idea to solve this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, improper-integrals

I'm not that good at integrating, sometimes the algebra comes after me.

That said, I'd like to solve this problem from the analysis point of view.

Knowing that $|\alpha| \neq |\beta|$, find $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} \cos (\alpha t) \sin (\beta t) dt. $$

I know the limit is zero coz I did integrate and simplify as usual, but I'd like to use something like the fact that if $\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x)=0$, and $v$ is bounded, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x) v(x) =0$, however in this case writing $v(x)= \int_{0}^{x} \cos (\alpha t) \sin (\beta t) dt $ is not bounded, in fact $|v(x)|\leq C t$ so even using the squeeze theorem the limit of $v(x)u(x)$ would be 1. (Why is that?).

I'd gladly hear some techniques in analysis to tackle this.

Thanks.

Comment: The direct calculation seems like the most natural approach in this context.

Comment: When $|\alpha| \ne |\beta|$, $v(x)$ is bounded!

Comment: Don't see it, how?

Comment: May I insist (maybe heavily) on the fact that your integral should be written $\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} \cos (\alpha t) \sin (\beta t) dt.$ ? (with $T \neq t$).

Comment: Why is that so bothering? like honestly don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I am not comfortable with your unique $t$ notation. It is preferable to write :

$$\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} \cos (\alpha t) \sin (\beta t) dt.$$

Solution : write the integrand under the form :

$$\tfrac12(\sin((\beta+\alpha)t)+\sin((\beta-\alpha)t))$$

and decompose your initial integral into 2 integrals.

Then use the fact that

$$\int_0^{T}\sin(\gamma t)dt=-\dfrac{1}{\gamma}(\cos(\gamma T)-1)$$

It is now easy to conclude...

Comment: The upper bound in your first integral should be T.

Comment: @LL 3.14 You are right. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Oh no sure, I think there are even more sophisticated ways of computing the integral, my questions was towards use a analysis-like-argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to compute explicitly your integral, at some point you have to use that your integrand is periodic and that it's integral is $0$ on a period $T$. Thus, the integral on $[0,t]$ with $t>T$ is reduced to an integral on an interval contained in $[0,T]$ and
$$
\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \cos(\alpha s)\sin(\beta s)\,\mathrm{d} s \leq \frac{1}{t} \int_0^T |\cos(\alpha s)\sin(\beta s)|\,\mathrm{d} s \leq \frac{T}{t}$$
which converges to $0$ when $t\to\infty$.